# PLS-00323: subprogram or cursor

Tags: plsql

I know that the most common issue for this is different names or parameters. 
Unless I'm having really bad eyes this is not the case here:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE my_api IS
  PROCEDURE sync_batch(x_return_status      OUT VARCHAR2);
END my_api;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY my_api IS
  PROCEDURE sync_batch(x_return_status      OUT VARCHAR2) IS
  BEGIN
    x_return_status := 'test';
  END sync_batch;
END my_api;
/
```

This results in:

> Errors for PACKAGE BODY MY_API: PLS-00323: subprogram or cursor 'SYNC_BATCH' is declared in a package specification and must be defined in the package body.

This occurs when I use sqlplus 11.2.0.1.0 64 Bit to connect to 12.1.0.2.0 64 Bit database in my test environment.
It does NOT occur when I use sqlplus 11.2.0.1.0 to connect to 11.2.0.1.0 64 Bit database at our customer.
I can add more procedures, but the error will always occur with this sync_batch procedure. Renaming the procedure doesn't solve the issue either, so I don't think it's a reserved name or something.

Does anyone have an idea what else could cause this?

**Update 2018-09-17:**
Well that is weird... I deleted the whole code and typed it again, now the error is gone.

When I did the same in my full code, the error disappeared for that procedure - but reappeared for a procedure further down, not directly the next one, but the one after.

I typed it in a .sql file in Visual Studio 2017, both before and when I retyped it, and copied the code from there to execute in SQLPlus. Could it be some encoding issue? VS says UTF-8 with signature, Codepage 65001, Line endings = Current Setting. My Oracle database uses NLS_CHARACTERSET = WE8MSWIN1252

Comment: Seems your specification was not compiled properly.

Comment: Wouldn't it normally say so? And like I said, the same code works fine on another database.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried to create package and package body with the exact script given by you. Created and compiled successfully both through IDE and through SQLPlus (however, I used 12* version of SQLPlus).

Are you creating package objects in correct order - firstly header and then body?
What happens when you create your package with compilation error and then try to recompile it? Doesn't that help?

I know that SQLPlus has problems with empty lines in the script, so be sure to not have them when executing scripts through SQLPlus.

Comment: SQL\*Plus is fine with blank lines in PL/SQL, it's just blank lines in SQL you have to be careful with (e.g. by setting `sqlblanklines on`).

Comment: As I stated in my update, there might be an issue with encoding or some "invisible" chars. But I have never encountered issues with blank lines separating one statement/procedure from the other. I wasn't aware of problems with blank lines within one statement/procedure, will keep an eye out for that

Answer (score 0):

The same versions as you have:

- client 11.2.0.1.0
- database 12.1.0.2.0 64-bit

Works OK. So ... no idea. A stupid suggestion, certainly, but - can you bounce the database?

---

```
M:\>sqlplus scott@orcl

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Pet Ruj 14 13:50:04 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL> set linesize 200
SQL> SELECT * FROM v$version;

BANNER                                                                               CON_ID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production              0
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production                                                    0
CORE    12.1.0.2.0      Production                                                        0
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production                                            0
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production                                                    0

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE my_api
  2  IS
  3     PROCEDURE sync_batch (x_return_status OUT VARCHAR2);
  4  END my_api;
  5  /

Package created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY my_api
  2  IS
  3     PROCEDURE sync_batch (x_return_status OUT VARCHAR2)
  4     IS
  5     BEGIN
  6        x_return_status := 'test';
  7     END sync_batch;
  8  END my_api;
  9  /

Package body created.

SQL>
SQL> DROP PACKAGE my_api;

Package dropped.

SQL>
```

Comment: Not before weekend. I'll give it a try.